# Missing Digikam geotagging on Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, digikam

After Kubuntu from 15.04 to 15.10 I miss the function to geotag my photos with digikam. The complete menu entry is missing. Is this an known bug? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I've had the same problem, it is missing in this version 4.12 of digiKam.
You have to upgrade DigiKam, this is a good solution in my case:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/08/install-latest-digikam-4-12-ubuntu/

Comment: You answer is essentially correct, but it is recommended to include the essential actions within the body of the answer.  That way, if the link to an outside source changes, the answer can still be used.

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot! Adding the repository ppa:philip5/extra works fine.
In the meanwhile I found a link to the bug report for this issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/marble/+bug/1511503